# Problem with removing data from realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

I have a small problem with remove data from Firebase Realtime database in users list made in Vue.js v-for.
On my small project I have database whose return to Vuex data about users, and when I deleted any user by firebase function **.remove()**, view in component is re-rendered but with duplicated data. Then my list looks like old list with this deleted user + one more time the list without this user. When i refresh the page, my list looks good, without this deleted user.

Anyone any thinks about that?

Component USER whose removing data in Firebase, it's works good because on Database this user is deleted without problems:

```js
methods: {
  removeUser() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`users/${this.user.id}`)
      .remove()
  }
}
```

I don't remove this manually from Vuex because this .remove() function run my function to save data in Vuex:

```js
initUsers() {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/users')
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach( childSnapshot => {
        this.usersList.push({
          username: childSnapshot.val().email,
          admin: childSnapshot.val().admin,
          id: childSnapshot.key
        })
      })
    });
},
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please, I think this is all to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that you don't re-initialize the `usersList` array in your listener.

So, you populate it once when the page is first displayed and then, when the record is deleted in the back end, the (still) existing records in the database are (again) pushed to the initial array.

If you do something like the following it should work:

```
initUsers() {
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/users')
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      this.usersList = [];  //<-- init to empty array
      snapshot.forEach( childSnapshot => {
        this.usersList.push({
          username: childSnapshot.val().email,
          admin: childSnapshot.val().admin,
          id: childSnapshot.key
        })
      })
    });
},
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this because it's logical move, but when I cleared this array on this position i don't have any records in my view by v-for (but in console.log I have array with no-duplicated data, only there looks good).

Comment: Ok, thanks, It's working. I went this way to debug why I don't have any results, and now looks good. Thank you!